# Pip command not working

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Whenever I try to do anything pip, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ImportError: cannot import name 'DependencyWarning'
```

I know this is a problem with the 'requests' package (it's version changed while I was working on something). The problem is, how do I upgrade 'requests' when pip doesn't work?

I am working in Windows in a virtualenv.

Comment: you could download it and install it manually. wheels are zip files. I've done that a lot of times

Comment: try might work -> [`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`]

Comment: did you activate the environment before you tried to update requests?

Comment: @Darkonaut yes. Everything works fine outside of environment

Comment: @SaketMittal no it doesn't work :(

Comment: Try `python -m pip install mypackage`.

Comment: Ups that should be a comment. Not sure If you understood me right... When you install with pip your prompt should be prefixed with your current environment after you activated it. Else you will update the package in your root and not for your environment.

Comment: Yes I know that. That's what I'm saying, when prefixed with current env pip doesn't work; otherwise it works

Comment: btw, why don't you use `conda ` when you have anaconda?

Comment: I need to execute many commands written in pip, don't want to use conda unless necessary

Comment: Well that could be the case right now. If pip doesn't work, try conda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it to work after trying a hacky solution I read here (credits to Andrew Chong).

Go to the **init**.py file causing the error. There will be a line -

```
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
```

Remove everything before urllib3 i.e. change it to -

```
from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
```

Now pip starts working again.